# Hiding and showing content on click using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In  a nutshell, i am creating a case study for a potential job, the employer wants me to use a React app to create it...

I want to create a button that has the start function that:

1. Hides original content
2. displays the hidden content,

i got the hidden content to show but the original content is still visible, any help?

my code below:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

function Body() {

    const [show, setShow] = useState(true);
    const [hide, setHidden] = useState(true);

  return (
      
    <>  
        <div className='container'>
            <div className="start-container">
                <h2>Click Start To View The Application</h2>
                <button onClick={ () => setShow(s => ! s) } className='btn'>Start!</button>         
            </div>
            
            {/* URL Link Input */}
            <div>
                {!show ? <form action="GET">
                    <input type="text" />
                    <button className='btn'>Submit</button>
                </form> : null }
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </>
    
  )
}

export default Body
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it dose not need hide state and you can toggle visibility just with show state. try this:

```
 { show ? <form action="GET">
  <input type="text" />
  <button className='btn'>Submit</button>
    </form> : null
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are close, you need to have the original content in the ternary so it's hidden once you toggle `show`. I also changed `setShow` to set `show` to `false` rather than the previous value since it doesn't matter because the button is not toggable because once you click it and can't re toggle the original content.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

function Body() {    
    const [show, setShow] = useState(true);

    return (
        <div className='container'>
            {show ? (
               <div className="start-container">
                  <h2>Click Start To View The Application</h2>
                  <button onClick={() => setShow(false)} className='btn'>Start!</button>         
               </div>
            ) : (
               <form action="GET">
                  <input type="text" />
                  <button className='btn'>Submit</button>
               </form>
            )
        </div>
  )
}

export default Body
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an `appStarted` state and then render your component conditionnally:

```js
const { useState } = React

function Body() {
  const [appStarted, setAppStarted] = useState(false)

  return (
    <div className="container">
      {appStarted ? (
        <div>
          <h2>Hidden Content</h2>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div className="start-container">
          <h2>Click Start To View The Application</h2>
          <button onClick={ () => setAppStarted(true) } className='btn'>Start!</button>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}


ReactDOM.render(<Body />, document.getElementById("root"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function Body() {
const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

return (
    <>
        <div className="container">
            {/* URL Link Input */}
            <div>
                {show ? (
                    <form action="GET">
                        <input type="text" />
                        <button className="btn">Submit</button>
                    </form>
                ) : (
                    <div className="start-container">
                        <h2>Click Start To View The Application</h2>
                        <button onClick={() => setShow(!show)} className="btn">
                            Start!
                        </button>
                    </div>
                )}
            </div>
        </div>
    </>
);
}

export default Body;
```

Comment: DUDE!, thank you so much!, it works!!!!!!! what a legend thank you!